# maven-2 build conflicts hudson/jenkins

Tags: maven-2, hudson, jenkins

I have 2 builds of the same project on the same Hudson/Jenkins server (they are running different build profiles). The both build when polling SCM, but I sometimes get the following error:

```
The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
```

This only started once I added the second build, so I'm assuming there is some sort of conflict. Does anyone know what's going on here?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: what maven goals are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your builds running at the same time, with the same Maven instance and the same local Maven repository? If so, then maybe you run into a filelock on that plugin jar. I have the same problem here, if two jobs are accessing the same Maven artifact at the same time, they fail, because Maven can't handle that.
I solved that with two Maven instances, with a separate local repository.
It could also help, if you set the VCS polling of the second job a minute after the first job.

Comment: I would think that both builds launch separate instances of maven. They each execute "mvn <goals>"...

Comment: Yes, the builds launch separate instances, but i meant two instances with the same settings.xml as configuration base, so they use the same local repository.

Comment: Oh yes, that is the case. They do use the same settings. I have now offset the build intervals of the two builds, so it seems to be working. Thanks.